# A decreasing sequence involving the divisor function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Define $N_k \geq 6$ to be the $k-th$ primorial number and let $\sigma(n)$ be the divisor function.

It *seems* that $u_k = \dfrac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k \log\log N_k}$ is a decreasing function ?

By computation, we find that the first few values  of $u_k$ (to 2dp)  are 
                                  $u_1 = 3.42, u_2 = 1.96, u_3 = 1.63, u_{4} = 1.46, u_5 = 1.38 \cdots$

Is there a known result from which this follows ?

As far as i'm aware, the only existing result *along these lines* is Gronwall's theorem, which says that $\lim$ $\sup u_k = e^{\gamma}$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

EDIT: By direct arithmetic that $u_k > u_{k+1}$ and simplifying, the problem reduces to showing that                                                      $\dfrac{\log\log N_{k+1}}{\log\log N_k} > \dfrac{1+p_{k+1}}{p_{k+1}}$, where $p_n$ denotes the $n-th$ prime.

Comment: Check out Merten's theorems.  If the values stay above the oscillations, then it is decreasing.  I don't know enough to say if there is a counterexample, but if there is k will likely be greater than 10^8.  Gerhard "Ask WolframAlpha.  Maybe It Knows" Paseman, 2016.02.11.

Comment: You misquote Gronwall's theorem which is about $\limsup_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(N)}{N\log\log N}$ rather than about $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k\log\log N_k}$. In fact it is easy to show that the latter equals $\frac{6}{\pi^2}e^\gamma=1.0827\dots$.

Comment: @G.H, thank you very much for both your comment and answer, which left me curious: is it then true that $\frac{\sigma(N_{k}}{N_{k}\log\log N_k }< e^{\gamma}$, for sufficiently large $N_k$ ?

Comment: @favoured The answer is yes, according to the preprint http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604314v2.pdf

Comment: @PaceNielsen, thank you very much. I assume you're referring to the second question that $\frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k\log\log N_k} < e^{\gamma}$ ?

Comment: @PaceNielsen: See my comment below my answer (a response to @favoured). The RH is not needed here, because $N_k$ is a very specific sequence for which the limit can be calculated.

Comment: @GHfromMO I don't believe that preprint needed RH to prove that Robin's inequality holds for square-free numbers.  I thought it proved it unconditionally.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: I see, I did not look at that preprint for lack of time. I just verified on the back of an envelope earlier that the limit is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}e^\gamma$, from which the inequality follows for large $k$. This was the original question. I understand now that it holds for all $k$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is probably no. Assume that $u_{k+1}<u_k$ for all $k$. Then
$$ \frac{1}{p_{k+1}}<\frac{\log\log N_{k+1}}{\log\log N_k}-1=\frac{\log\frac{\log N_{k+1}}{\log N_k}}{\log\log N_k}<\frac{\frac{\log N_{k+1}}{\log N_k}-1}{\log\log N_k}=\frac{\log p_{k+1}}{\log N_k\log\log N_k}.$$
In particular,
$$ \theta(p_k)\log\theta(p_k)<p_{k+1}\log p_{k+1},$$
whence
$$ \theta(p_k)<p_{k+1}. $$
By Littlewood's theorem, the left hand side exceeds $p_k+p_k^{1/2}$ infinitely often, while it is widely believed that the right hand side is smaller than $p_k+p_k^{1/3}$ for every large $k$. So, if we believe the last upper bound, there are infinitely many counterexamples (but these might occur very rarely).

**Added.** By quoting Littlewood's theorem a bit more precisely, we get a contradiction already by Legendre's conjecture that there is a prime number between any two large consecutive squares.

Comment: @G.H, thank you very much for both your comment and answer, which left me curious: is it then true that $\frac{\sigma(N_{k}}{N_{k}\log\log N_k }< e^{\gamma}$, for sufficiently large $N_k$ ?

Comment: @favoured: Yes, because the fraction tends to $6/\pi^2$ times the right hand side.

Comment: @ GH : what is $\theta(p_k)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: $\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log p$ is the first Chebyshev function. See at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function

Comment: GH, I had not noticed this question. It appears that person(s?) are switching various versions of RH. In particular, see the enjoyable paper by Planat et al about the Nicolas criterion, http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613 which shows that a related sequence, if increasing forever, proves RH but disproves Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for all these papers (Nicolas's etc.), I was not aware of them. In fact I can now quickly answer the other question (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/231925/a-lower-bound-involving-the-divisor-function-and-primorial-numbers).