# A lower bound involving the divisor function and primorial numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is known that
$\lim$ $\sup \dfrac{\sigma(N_k)}{e^{\gamma}N_k \log\log N_k}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$,

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $N_k$ is the $k-th$ primorial number.

But is it true that, for sufficiently large $N_k$,

$ \dfrac{\sigma(N_k)}{e^{\gamma}N_k \log\log N_k} >\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking whether $\forall k_0$ there exists a $k \geq k_0$ such that $\dfrac{\sigma(N_k)}{e^{\gamma}N_k \log\log N_K}>\frac{6}{\pi^2}$? That statement is at least consistent with the proven $\lim\sup$ value (and would be non-trivial to prove or disprove).  The way your posed question reads to me, it would mean "$\exists k_0$ such that $\forall k>k_0 :\dfrac{\sigma(N_k)}{e^{\gamma}N_k \log\log N_K}>\frac{6}{\pi^2} $, and that statement is false.

Comment: Actually the $\limsup$ here is really a limit.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670635/on-the-asymptotic-limit-of-the-divisor-function

Comment: $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$ is the **sum** of divisors function, editing the tittle could be a good idea

Comment: @GHfromMO, this does happen infinitely often.

Comment: so the question is if $\displaystyle\sum_{n \in A_k} \frac{|\mu_n|}{n} > e^{-\gamma} \frac{6}{\pi^2} \ln \ln N_k$ where $A_k$ is the set of integers with prime divisors all $\le p_k$ the $k$th prime.

Comment: separating $\sum_{n \in A_k} $ as $\sum_{n \le p_k} + \sum_{ \ldots}$ and that $\sum_{n \le M} \frac{|\mu_n|}{n} \sim \frac{\ln M}{\zeta(2)}$, but I don't know how $\ln \ln N_k$ is related to $\ln p_k$

Comment: @WillJagy: The affirmative answer to the OP's question is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis. Thanks for helping me out with the references. (Does that make me a non-believer in the Riemann Hypothesis? Just kidding.)

Comment: @GHfromMO, thanks for working it out, I couldn't tell. A general comment, Robin was a student of Nicolas, and Robin's criterion is fairly well known as an equivalent of RH, but the criterion of Nicolas seems much less well known.

Answer (score 5):

The affirmative answer to your question is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis, and this was observed by [Solé and Planat](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1825) as a consequence of Nicolas's [earlier work](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphi83.pdf). I recall their argument briefly.

Assume that the Riemann Hypothesis holds. Then Nicolas's Theorem 2 (a) implies readily that $\frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k \log\log N_k} >\frac{6}{\pi^2}e^\gamma$ holds for all $k$. Now assume that the Riemann Hypothesis fails. Then Nicolas's Theorem 3 (c) implies readily that the inequality holds for infinitely many $k$'s, and also that the inequality fails for infinitely many $k$'s.

Comment: I see, this is a different arXiv article, Choie is not involved in this one.

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, and this was mentioned in the article that you showed me.

Answer (score 3):

From Jean-Louis Nicolas, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/ in  [article](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphi83.pdf) we find that there are **infinitely many primorials** $n$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n} > \frac{\phi(n)}{n} $$
Therefore, infinitely often,
$$ \frac{1}{e^\gamma \log \log n}  \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}> \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} =  \frac{\sigma(n) \phi(n)}{n^2} > \frac{6}{\pi^2} $$
from Theorem 329 and footnote on page 267 of Hardy and Wright.

I am unable to tell whether your inequality for **sufficiently large primorials** is equivalent to RH. You are mixing two types of behavior, extreme behavior for primorials is the Nicolas criterion, while that for colossally abundant numbers is the Robin criterion. The inequalities in Hardy and Wright linking $\phi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$ are not tight enough to cross the conditions.